# change style of QTableWidgetItem depending on flags

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I have a `QTableWidget` with a few `QTableWidgetItem`'s in it. To style it I use:

```
QTableWidget::item {
    ...
}
```

Now a few of the items are read only. How can I color them differently using the stylesheet? Normaly I would use a property and then select with:

```
QTableWidgetItem[readOnly="true"]
```

But this doesn't work since we define the style of the `QTableWidget` and `QTableWidgetItem` has no method `setProperty`.

Comment: I think you should be querying the state of the QTableWidgetItem in a if statement and set the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the styling should be

```
WIDGET::SUB-CONTROL:PSEUDO-STATE
```

Please try as said below.

```
QTableWidget::item:read-only {
     background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #e7effd, stop: 1 #cbdaf1);
}
```

For list of Sub-Controls and Pseudo-States refer below link:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#selection-color-prop

Comment: Great that did work with a minor tweak. I needed to use `enabled` instead of `read-only`. One additional question: I like the qt docs, except for the style sheet part. Do you by any chance now a good source for an easy cheat sheet showing all properties of each widget and selector?

Comment: Sorry I do not have any. I follow only this link ---- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html  ....actually it covers most of the information. It has complete list of sub-controls and list of pseudo states.